# Yii2 update the table each month

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Please tell me how to make a table update every month / year.
 For example I have a table Points:
- id
- user_id
- points
I need to reset it every month. How can I do it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can create cron console command. Please check the following: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/646/how-to-implement-cron-in-yii-2/

1. Create console/controllers/TestController.php:

   ```
   <?php

   namespace console\controllers;

   use yii\console\Controller;

   class TestController extends Controller {
       public function actionIndex() {
           echo "cron service runnning";
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add it to server cron to run monthly e.g.:

   0    22   1   *   *   /usr/bin/php /path/to/your/yii test/index

in example above it will run each 1-st day of month 22:00 server time.
Also, please check [Unix Cron Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) for more details how to set up cron execution time.

Comment: I would suggest to also add some kind of simple password check at least, so table doesnt get reset by random person, lets say as GET parameter.

Comment: I create TestController.php with actionIndex() in folder app\cron\ ,then i open openserver console, I turn into a folder with project and run 0 0 1 */1 */usr/bin/php yii test/index and see "0 is not an internal or external command"

Comment: Viskas, cron does not work on Windows. You should check Scheduled tasks e.g.: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649816(v=wps.630).aspx https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726974.aspx https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993(v=ws.11).aspx app\cron\ is wrong folder. Correct folder for cron controller is console\controllers\